# Laravel Passport Grant Token — Set custom username and password fields

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, access-token, laravel-passport

I am working on project which has separate model for users — `App\Models\Customer`. And also it has own authorisation fields — `Email` and `cust_password`. And also password is hashed by `password_hash` function.

In my `config/auth.php` in `providers` section I set up my custom model:

```php
'providers' => [
    'customers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
    ],
],
```

So I am trying to implement [Laravel Grand Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#password-grant-tokens). I need to make request to `/oauth/token/` with client (which was previously created with custom `provider` field) and customer credentials as like this:

```php
/** @var \Laravel\Passport\Client $client */

$response = Http::asForm
    ->post('https://localhost/oauth/token/', [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'username' => 'example@example.com',
        'password' => password_hash('my-password'),
    ]);
```

But I am receiving error: `invalid_grant — The user credentials were incorrect`.

I assume that Passport doesn't know where to find my `Email` and `cust_password` fields. Is there any way to set custom login and password fiends?

Thanks you any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wasn't attentive enough, there is special topics for this situations:

Customizing The Username Field https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#customizing-the-username-field

Customizing The Password Validation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#customizing-the-password-validation